# Compare / Equatable weak generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, weak-references

I want to create an array of weak referenced delegates like so...

```
fileprivate class WeakDelegate<T:AnyObject> {

    weak var value:T?

    init (value:T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}


class Radio {

    private var delegates = [WeakDelegate<AnyObject>]()
}
```

So far so good...? what I'd like to do also is tidy up my array in these two ways...

1.

```
func removeDeadDelegates() {

    let liveDelegates = delegates.filter { $0.value != nil }
    delegates = liveDelegates
}
```

and 2.

```
func remove<T>(specificDelegate:T) {

    let filteredDelegates = delegates.filter { $0.value != specificDelegate }
    listeners = filteredDelegates
}
```

Says `Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'`

Now I can just add this to make the warning go away like this...

```
    let liveDelegates = delegates.filter {

        if let d = specificDelegate as? _OptionalNilComparisonType {
            return $0.value != d
        }

        return true
    }
```

but this cast doesn't work...

I'm concerned because I'm not sure what this means... can anyone explain why I can't compare generics with `==` and why this cast is failing?

Thanks for your time

*EDIT*

Like this?

```
func remove<T:AnyObject>(delegate:T) {

    let filteredDelegates = delegates.filter { $0.value != delegate }
    delegates = filteredDelegates
}
```

No joy sadly...

Comment: Try restricting `T` to `AnyObject`: `func remove<T: AnyObject>`

Comment: @cristik edited... sadly it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instances of a class type can be compared with the “identical to”
`===` and “not identical to” `!==` operators:

```
func remove(specificDelegate: AnyObject) {
    let filteredDelegates = delegates.filter { $0.value !== specificDelegate }
    delegates = filteredDelegates
}
```

The same works for a generic method

```
func remove<T:AnyObject>(specificDelegate: T) {
    let filteredDelegates = delegates.filter { $0.value !== specificDelegate }
    delegates = filteredDelegates
}
```

(but I do not yet see the advantage of doing so).

Comment: and agreed, there's no value in adding the generic there

Comment: @Magoo - In fact, if you're going to declare `delegates` as `WeakDelegate<AnyObject>()`, there's no point in using generics at all.